# Return Unique Values in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

As a result of below code, I am wanting to return only unique values. As an example, if there are three 'Company not found' items that will be returned in the array, I would like it to be written only once. Can anyone help?

```
function findInvalidCardCompanies(invalidCards) {
const invalidCompany=[];

for (let j=0; j<invalidCards.length; j++) {
let inv=invalidCards[j];
if(inv[1]===3) {invalidCompany.push('Amex')}
else if (inv[1]===4) {invalidCompany.push('Visa')}
else if (inv[1]===5) {invalidCompany.push ('Mastercard')}
else if (inv[1]===6) {invalidCompany.push('Discover')}
else {invalidCompany.push('Company not found')};
}
return invalidCompany;
};
console.log(findInvalidCardCompanies(findInvalidCards(batch)));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: @WillD I saw it but couldn't figure out how to implement into my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the javascript Set Object to remove the duplicate items. The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references. [More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
 // Use to remove duplicate elements from the array 

const numbers = [2,3,4,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,5,32,3,4,5]

console.log([...new Set(numbers)]) 

// [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 32]
```

So your function will look something like this:

```
function findInvalidCardCompanies(invalidCards) {
const invalidCompany=[];

for (let j=0; j<invalidCards.length; j++) {
let inv=invalidCards[j];
if(inv[1]===3) {invalidCompany.push('Amex')}
else if (inv[1]===4) {invalidCompany.push('Visa')}
else if (inv[1]===5) {invalidCompany.push ('Mastercard')}
else if (inv[1]===6) {invalidCompany.push('Discover')}
else {invalidCompany.push('Company not found')};
}
return [...new Set(invalidCompany)];
};
console.log(findInvalidCardCompanies(findInvalidCards(batch)));
```

Comment: If I wanted to use if (invalidCompany.indexOf('Mastercard') === -1), what would be the best way to add it to code? Especially for the 'Company not found' part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). *A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.*

You can add to a set with the add Function. If you add an already existing value, it will be ignored.

```
function findInvalidCardCompanies(invalidCards) {
const invalidCompany= new Set();

for (let j=0; j<invalidCards.length; j++) {
let inv=invalidCards[j];
if(inv[1]===3) {invalidCompany.add('Amex')}
else if (inv[1]===4) {invalidCompany.add('Visa')}
else if (inv[1]===5) {invalidCompany.add ('Mastercard')}
else if (inv[1]===6) {invalidCompany.add('Discover')}
else {invalidCompany.add('Company not found')};
}
return invalidCompany;
};
console.log(findInvalidCardCompanies(findInvalidCards(batch)));
```